# Sending a JSON parameter to service

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-android

I want to use rxjava and retrofit.
this is my retrofit builder:

```
Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl(UrlManager.API_HOST)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

and okHttpClient:

```
public OkHttpClient client(HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor, Cache cache) {
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cache(cache)
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
}
```

In my Login Activity I insert my user and password and when loginButton is clicked this method in called:

```
public DisposableObserver observeLoginButton() {
        return view.observeLoginBtn()
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext(new Consumer<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Object o) throws Exception {
                        view.loadButtonAnimation(); //load animation
                    }
                })
                .map(new Function<Object, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String apply(Object o) throws Exception {
                        return view.getUserAndPassword(); // get userName and password as a string from edittext
                    }
                })
                .switchMap(new Function<String, Observable<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<String> apply(String s) throws Exception {
                        String[] info = s.split(" "); // split user name and pass
                        return model.getLoginCookie(info[0],info[1]); // send userName and pass to model and call my service
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .subscribeWith(view.observer());
    }
```

For test i have inserted myself login info to sending a service. this is my getLoginCookie method:

```
public Observable<String> getLoginCookie(String userName, String password) {
    Map<String, Object> obj = new ArrayMap<>();
    obj.put("username", "JuJzWgbsDJ0lUlFYVzoxWg");
    obj.put("password", "DD0vCYmzJuIPff9iKUpfQA");
    obj.put("customCredential", "6298f927-f98a-44eb-a312-780674a76245,Mobile89954324581380882887");
    obj.put("isPersistent", false);


    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(
            MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"),
            (new JSONObject(obj)).toString());
    return service.getAuthentication(body);
}
```

My service work as a json parametr.So in order to i have used RequestBody to convert my map to json. Then i have called my service :

```
@POST(UrlManager.AUTHENTICATION+"Login")
Observable<String> getAuthentication(@Body RequestBody params);
```

When i run my app and click on login button i got this:

```
D/Payesh: --> POST http://****/Authentication.svc/json/Login (183-byte body)
W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/data/com.groot.payesh/cache/okhttp_cache/journal.tmp
D/Payesh: <-- HTTP FAILED: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
I/----->: apply: null
```

**1-** Why I got android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException ?

**2-** How could i trace that my parameter is correct is send to my web service and does connect is established or not? I have just got `java.lang.NullPointerException: The supplied value is null` on `onError(Throwable e)` in observer.

Comment: What is actually you doing in `view.observeLoginBtn()` line?

Comment: @AbuYousuf nothing.It is just button listener that implemented by Rx.

Comment: @AbuYousuf `public Observable<Object> observeLoginBtn() {
        return RxView.clicks(mBinding.buttonLogin);}`

Comment: please post you that relates to click event

Comment: @AbuYousuf I did send. look top post.`public Observable<Object> observeLoginBtn() { return RxView.clicks(mBinding.buttonLogin);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I got android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException ?

You are subscribing on `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` and observing on `Schedulers.io()`. That means you are doing network request on Main Thread. **Switch Thread** before network request by adding `.observeOn(Schedulers.io())` before `switchMap`. And finally Observe On Main Thread if you are doing any view related task after finish.

```
        return view.observeLoginBtn()
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext(new Consumer<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Object o) throws Exception {
                    view.loadButtonAnimation(); //load animation
                }
            })
            .map(new Function<Object, String>() {
                @Override
                public String apply(Object o) throws Exception {
                    return view.getUserAndPassword(); // get userName and password as a string from edittext
                }
            })
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .switchMap(new Function<String, Observable<String>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<String> apply(String s) throws Exception {
                    String[] info = s.split(" "); // split user name and pass
                    return model.getLoginCookie(info[0],info[1]); // send userName and pass to model and call my service
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribeWith(view.observer());
```

For

```
 remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/data/com.groot.payesh/cache/okhttp_cache/journal.tmp
```

make sure hoy have successfully created FIle for cache.

> How could i trace that my parameter is correct is send to my web
>   service and does connect is established or not?

As you have  used `HttpLoggingInterceptor` this will print all info about your request like `Header`, `Body`, `Response`.

Comment: when I add `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` like you, when i clicked on my button ,My app crashed `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method load(View) in the activity class com.groot.payesh.activities.login.LoginActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.FrameLayout with id 'buttonLogin'`

Comment: I have used `HttpLoggingInterceptor` but nothing displayed just that i mentioned above

Comment: `view` what instance is this?  you have to post all related code. Please edit your question and post all related code?

Comment: I am using MVP architecture. view is layout that inflate my LoginLayout.

Comment: Edited answer check now